# The requested resource is not available in REST

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat

I have problem with my REST using `@FormParam`, please help me, I don't know why this project doesn't work with tomcat 7 and java 7 on Eclipse Luna :(

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.adam.core</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/core</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.adam.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>RESTform</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>RESTform Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>RESTform</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**UserForm.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Suma REST @FormQuery </h1>

    <form action="core/user/add" method="post">
        <p>
            Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Number 3: <input type="text" name="number3" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Number 4: <input type="text" name="number4" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Number 5: <input type="text" name="number5" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Suma" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and **UserService.java**

```
package com.adam.core;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/user")
public class UserService {

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    public Response addUser(
        @FormParam("number1") int number1,
        @FormParam("number2") int number2,
        @FormParam("number3") int number3,
        @FormParam("number4") int number4,
        @FormParam("number5") int number5){

        return Response.status(200).entity("Suma : " + (number1+number2+number3+number4+number5)).build();
    }
}
```

[image: layout]

My console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /RESTform threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5218)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Should `core` really be part of the URL? I think `user/add` is enough.

Comment: Its just core :)
with or wihtout core is the same error

Comment: its clearly classnotfoundexception you are missing one of its jar

Comment: remove the jersey core dependency from pom...jersey server will automatically download the appropriate core jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working. I add asm.jar to tomcat and to project and it's fine :D
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the Problem is ClassNotFoundException , missing one of its dependies..

i think you need to put the dependency as -

use this

```
       <dependency>    
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also remove the jersey core dependency , the hersey server will automatically download the rest of depenedent jars

Comment: check if lib is getting the jars in webapp  inside tomcat

Comment: yeah the same exception unfortunately...
Tomcat is working good without project

Comment: no , go to tomcat/webapps/{your project directory}/lib  ...check the jars getting in lib directory

Comment: in tomcat/webapps i have only 5 folders: docs, examples,host-manager, manager and ROOT. My folder name is RESTform

Comment: yes, go to your folder and under that go to WEB-INF , check for lib folder and check if contains all required jars...probably the lib folder might not getting the jars from the maven build

Comment: i dont have my project folder in tomcat/webapp...
but in eclipse in this folder i have jersey-core and jersey-servlet 1.17.1 and jersey-server 1.18.1